# Struggling with re-organisation of Json data structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert this JSON:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "ac": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "ac": 0
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "ac": 0
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ac": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "ac": 0
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ac": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "ac": 0
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ac": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ac": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "ac": 0
        }
    ]
]
```

into that data structure:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "ac": [1,1,1,1,1,1]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "ac": [1,1,1,0,0,0]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "ac": [1,0,0,0,0,0]
        }
    ]
]
```

I am using JavaScript/ node to do so, but I cannot get it to work. Can anyone help me to write a loop that can do so?

edit:
What I tried is, the following, but I guess it doesn't help a lot because it is still not the output that I need

```
var acc_array = [];
var a_id;
for(var y=0; y<data.length; y++) { //151
    if(y<data.length-1){
        a_id = data[y].a_id;
        if(a_id == data[y].a_id) {
            acc_array[y] = new Array();
            acc_array[y].push(data[y].acc);
        }
    }
    if(y==data.length-1){
        acc_array[y] = new Array();
        a_id = data[y].a_id;
        if(a_id == data[y].a_id) {
            acc_array[y].push(data[y].acc);
        }
        jsonfile.writeFile("a.json", acc_array, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: is it allways in order of id 1, 2, 3?

Comment: because it s an JS array, the order can never be guaranteed no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a nested loop and a hash table for collecting items with the same `id`.

```js
var data = [[{ id: 1, ac: 1 }, { id: 2, ac: 1 }, { id: 3, ac: 1 }], [{ id: 1, ac: 1 }, { id: 2, ac: 1 }, { id: 3, ac: 0 }], [{ id: 1, ac: 1 }, { id: 2, ac: 1 }, { id: 3, ac: 0 }], [{ id: 1, ac: 1 }, { id: 2, ac: 0 }, { id: 3, ac: 0 }], [{ id: 1, ac: 1 }, { id: 2, ac: 0 }, { id: 3, ac: 0 }], [{ id: 1, ac: 1 }, { id: 2, ac: 0 }, { id: 3, ac: 0 }]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (o) {
        hash[o.id] || result.push(hash[o.id] = { id: o.id, ac: [] });
        hash[o.id].ac.push(o.ac);
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Array#concat everything to a single array, then use a Array#reduce with a helper object to get an array of the objects that you want:

```js
var data = [[{"id":1,"ac":1},{"id":2,"ac":1},{"id":3,"ac":1}],[{"id":1,"ac":1},{"id":2,"ac":1},{"id":3,"ac":0}],[{"id":1,"ac":1},{"id":2,"ac":1},{"id":3,"ac":0}],[{"id":1,"ac":1},{"id":2,"ac":0},{"id":3,"ac":0}],[{"id":1,"ac":1},{"id":2,"ac":0},{"id":3,"ac":0}],[{"id":1,"ac":1},{"id":2,"ac":0},{"id":3,"ac":0}]];

var hash = Object.create(null);
var result = [].concat(...data)
  .reduce(function(r, o) {
    var item = hash[o.id];
    
    if(!item) {
      item = hash[o.id] = { id: o.id, ac: [] };    
      r.push(item);
    }
    
    item.ac.push(o.ac);
    
    return r;
  }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```